# Java JUNIT TDD Assert Test

Tags: java, tdd

I've got an Address Book and part of the requirements is to return the entries from that address book. Ideally this should be simple enough, I have a forloop looping through my linkedlist until it's not equal to null. I'm then just calling the get methods for all the information e.g. 
list.get(i).getAge();
list.get(i).getName();

However I have to do TDD Junit so I need to provide an assert to check whether it has been correctly implemented and the expected value (all entries) is equal to the entries returned. Any ideas of how i can do this assert test? I'm struggling with inputting the expected value, since it's multiple entries I'm not sure what the expected value would be... if it was one entry then the expectation would be the one object however since it's multiple at a time i'm unsure.

Sorry if this is brief/blanned don't want to post code in case people in my class copy.

Comment: What Type (Generics) has your list? Is it a "Person"?

Comment: yes so name, age, gender ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are writing a unit test to check the implementation of each getter function of a class called Person.

Each method should have its own test method (i.e. testgetAge, testgetName, etc), and in theory, each test case should have its own method too. For example you may have a method that tests that a persons age is never greater than 200, or never less than 0, etc.

The reason you want these in separate cases is so when one test fails, you dont have to figure out which condition has been violated.

However, in some cases - with simple classes this is not a practical. Instead you should write a data provider for your test method, the provider will have a list of pairs of data (any format you like) where One item in the pair is the expected value, and another item in the pair is the object being tested.

for example:

```
private final List<Object[]> people = new ArrayList<>()
public void setup(){
   people.add(30, new Person(30, "Jeff"))
   people.add(50, new Person(50, "Bill"))
}

public void testGetAge(){
    setup();
    for(Object[] entry : people){
        self::assertEquals(entry[0], entry[1].getAge());
    }
}
```

Some testing frameworks support providing data providers by annotations